# I deleted my packages folder now I can't build in VS2019

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I was having trouble with a dependency downgrade error (as it turned out, due to a bad git conflict resolution I had two references for the same package in the csproj file with different versions - anyway, not the issue).

One of the things I tried while attempting to discover this was deleting the package cache from `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` - I deleted the entire `packages` folder.

I then discovered there were duplicate package references in the `csproj` file and thought "ok, I'll just remove the duplicate and do a `dotnet restore Blah.sln` and all will well. Nope. I kept getting a build error:

```
metadata file microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers.dll could not be found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After *a lot* of Googling, it turns out that to solve this issue I needed to open the solution in **VS2017** and run a rebuild command. Doing this restored the required packages and I was then able to build successfully in **VS2019**

[This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1215) led me to the answer, although isn't specific to the issue I was having necessarily